# Multiple variables

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I am creating a form that would edit existing comments.
It contains a textarea with old comment (text) and a button that is submit.
All I need is to sent newComment through ajax into another script.
The alert here shows me only the old comment, while it should show me that new one. Could someone give me any clue? Seems like button is not submiting it or something. But when i use type submit the website is reloading that I dont want at all.

```
function editComment(id, text){
    var thisId = "#" + id;
    $(thisId).replaceWith("<form>\n\
                          <textarea id='newComment'>" + text + "</textarea>\n\
                          <input type='button' id='submit' value='save'>\n\
                          </form>");

    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var newComment =  document.getElementById('newComment').innerHTML;               
        alert(newComment);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/editComment',
            data: "newComment",
        });                     
    });
}
```

Comment: try changing $.ajax type to 'submit' instead of 'get' cause i think youre trying to post your new data to the backend, not get data from the backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

```
function editComment(id, text){
    var thisId = "#" + id;
    $(thisId).replaceWith("<form>\n\
                          <textarea id='newComment'>" + text + "</textarea>\n\
                          <input type='button' id='submit' value='save'>\n\
                          </form>");

    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var newComment =  document.getElementById('newComment').value;               
        alert(newComment);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/editComment',
            data: "newComment",
        });                     
    });
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpercy/193g8pyx/)

Comment: Simply helped me. Thanks!

Comment: You should accept the answer if it worked for you. Glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to stop the form submitting by preventing its default action. So in your case it would look something like this.

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newComment =  document.getElementById('newComment').innerHTML;               
        alert(newComment);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/editComment',
            data: "newComment",
        });                     
    });
```

I would also recommend putting the code that shows the new comment in the success function of the ajax call because if it were to fail for what ever reason you would not want to show the new comment anyway. For example.

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
        var newComment =  document.getElementById('newComment').innerHTML;               
        alert(newComment);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/editComment',
            data: "newComment",
            success: function (data) {
                $(thisId).replaceWith("<form>\n\
                          <textarea id='newComment'>" + text + "</textarea>\n\
                          <input type='button' id='submit' value='save'>\n\
                          </form>");
            }
        });                     
    });
```

Also if you are using jQuery you might as well use jQuery for everything.

```
$('#newComment').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click','#submit',function() {
        var newComment =  document.getElementById('newComment').innerHTML;               
        alert(newComment);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/editComment',
            data: "newComment",
        });     
       return false;                
    });
```

Use on event, you are dynamically creating submit button,and return false to prevent submit button to reload page

Answer (score 2):

You can use form and stop reloading by returning false.
ie,

```
return false;
```

at the end of the function.

ex:

```
 $('#submit').click(function() {
            var newComment =  document.getElementById('newComment').innerHTML;               
            alert(newComment);
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'get',
                  url: '/editComment',
                  data: "newComment",
              });
            return false;         
          });
```